# How can I catch all exceptions thrown through reading / writing a file?

Tags: java, file, exception, try-catch

In Java, is there any way to get (catch) all `exceptions` instead of catching the exceptions individually?

Comment: and I will catch all those specific Exceptions with catch(Exception e){}??

Comment: yeah.  Since Exception is the base class of all exceptions, it will catch any exception.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

If you want, you can add throws clauses to your methods.  Then you don't have to catch checked methods right away.  That way, you can catch the `exceptions` later (perhaps at the same time as other `exceptions`).

The code looks like:

```
public void someMethode() throws SomeCheckedException {

    //  code

}
```

Then later you can deal with the `exceptions` if you don't wanna deal with them in that method.

To catch all exceptions some block of code may throw you can do: (This will also catch `Exceptions` you wrote yourself)

```
try {

    // exceptional block of code ...

    // ...

} catch (Exception e){

    // Deal with e as you please.
    //e may be any type of exception at all.

}
```

The reason that works is because `Exception` is the base class for all exceptions.  Thus any exception that may get thrown is an `Exception` (Uppercase 'E').

If you want to handle your own exceptions first simply add a `catch` block before the generic Exception one.

```
try{    
}catch(MyOwnException me){
}catch(Exception e){
}
```

Answer (score 106):

While I agree it's not good style to catch a raw Exception, there are ways of handling exceptions which provide for superior logging, and the ability to handle the unexpected. Since you are in an exceptional state, you are probably more interested in getting good information than in response time, so instanceof performance shouldn't be a big hit.

```
try{
    // IO code
} catch (Exception e){
    if(e instanceof IOException){
        // handle this exception type
    } else if (e instanceof AnotherExceptionType){
        //handle this one
    } else {
        // We didn't expect this one. What could it be? Let's log it, and let it bubble up the hierarchy.
        throw e;
    }
}
```

However, this doesn't take into consideration the fact that IO can also throw Errors. Errors are not Exceptions. Errors are a under a different inheritance hierarchy than Exceptions, though both share the base class Throwable. Since IO can throw Errors, you may want to go so far as to catch Throwable

```
try{
    // IO code
} catch (Throwable t){
    if(t instanceof Exception){
        if(t instanceof IOException){
            // handle this exception type
        } else if (t instanceof AnotherExceptionType){
            //handle this one
        } else {
            // We didn't expect this Exception. What could it be? Let's log it, and let it bubble up the hierarchy.
        }
    } else if (t instanceof Error){
        if(t instanceof IOError){
            // handle this Error
        } else if (t instanceof AnotherError){
            //handle different Error
        } else {
            // We didn't expect this Error. What could it be? Let's log it, and let it bubble up the hierarchy.
        }
    } else {
        // This should never be reached, unless you have subclassed Throwable for your own purposes.
        throw t;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would argue that you should catch each exception explicitly, but the question explicitly asked how to catch everything a block of code would throw.

Comment: That throwable was useful.

Comment: This is the solution I was looking for, I needed an if else for exception handling. Thanks

Comment: Throwable tip is really useful.

Comment: If you catch Throwables you should keep in mind that the VirtualMachineErrors such as StackOverflowError or OutOfMemoryError does not allow you to do much more than logging. They are outside of the applications control and you can not handle them.

Comment: Your suggestion of using Throwable worked perfectly to catch errors on a cordova plugin! Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

Catch the base exception 'Exception'

```
   try { 
         //some code
   } catch (Exception e) {
        //catches exception and all subclasses 
   }
```

Comment: If you write this code, you are almost certainly doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: @George  Why did you say that?

Comment: @George Not necessarily, if you deal with something that has a lot of sensitive entry parameters and it is very complicated to verify the validity of each one of them, catching all kind of exceptions once the working cases are properly tested is the way to go. It will make the code clear and way less mindf*k than a huge and potentially heavy condition.

Comment: Most coders I have worked with put nothing in their catch statements, so using this try catch snippet is actually better than catching a bunch of different exception types and not doing anything with it

Comment: @LouisMorda I disagree, catching every Exception subclass and not doing anything based on them (ignoring them) is worse than only catching some specific exceptions and ignoring them. If you catch some Exception types and don't do anything with the information, you have no chance of knowing what went wrong in those situations, but if you catch all Exception subclasses you have no chance of knowing what went wrong in a much large number of situations.
Consider how you would handle bug reports without the information from the exceptions, like stacktraces and messages.

Comment: After 6 years of discussion I should add - this was provided as an example on how to catch all exceptions which is what the original question asked.  The answer is simple - catch the base exception.  If you want to make sure you are handling exceptions properly please do your research.  A good place to start:  Google "java exception handling best practices"

Answer (score 10):

You may catch multiple exceptions in single catch block.

```
try{
  // somecode throwing multiple exceptions;
} catch (Exception1 | Exception2 | Exception3 exception){
  // handle exception.
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Do you mean catch an `Exception` of any *type* that is thrown, as opposed to just specific Exceptions?

If so:

```
try {
   //...file IO...
} catch(Exception e) {
   //...do stuff with e, such as check its type or log it...
}
```

Comment: What should I do for the ones that are not specific??

Comment: and I will catch all those specific Exceptions with catch(Exception e){}??

Answer (score 7):

It is bad practice to catch **Exception** -- it's just too broad, and you may miss something like a **NullPointerException** in your own code.

For most file operations, **IOException** is the root exception. Better to catch that, instead.

Comment: It is bad practice to catch Exception. why? downvote bad explained

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is.

```
try
{
    //Read/write file
}catch(Exception ex)
{
    //catches all exceptions extended from Exception (which is everything)
}
```