# Handling all Java Exceptions in one catch block

Tags: java, eclipse, exception, error-handling, try-catch

When I try to write this code :

```
catch (Exception  | OutOfMemoryError| NumberFormatException| SQLException| IOException  e){
}
```

I get the error:
"The exception NumberFormatException is already caught by the alternative Exception" 
I understand it great and from first thinking it's make sense because Exception is the general one.
but when I write this code:

```
 catch (Exception  | OutOfMemoryError  e){
    }
```

It works without any problems so now I start to get confused why don't I get the previous error. Is OutOfMemmoryError will catch things that Exception won't catch?
If I Want to make catch that will include all of exceptions and errors possible what should i write?
I just understood that this:

```
catch (Exception e){
}
```

won't catch for me all the exceptions and errors so what will do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I catch all the exceptions that will be thrown through reading and writing a file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075895/how-can-i-catch-all-the-exceptions-that-will-be-thrown-through-reading-and-writi)

Comment: You should look at the inheritance hierarchy of `Throwable`.

Comment: OutOfMemeoryError is of type java.lang.Error, not Throwable..

Comment: @StanislavPalatnik [Error is Throwable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html)

Comment: @FastSnail what does || meaning? when i tried it now it gave me syntax error
and i am not trying just to solve the error. i want to understand the logic of all this exceptions and create catch block that will catch all error and exceptions

Comment: @user3100708 That comment was just wrong and it's been deleted.  `||` is not correct syntax.

Comment: @StanislavPalatnik so how do you think i can catch all the exceptions and error in one catch block?

Comment: @amit: Meant `Exception`.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679330/catching-java-lang-outofmemoryerror

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To better understand what's happening, take a look at the Java exception hierarchy. A broad overview can be seen in [this diagram](http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/exception%20hierarchy%20in%20java.png).

When you catch multiple exceptions in a single catch block, you should only use the "topmost" exceptions in catch. For example, your error will persist in something like

```
catch (IOException | FileNotFoundException e)
```

since `FileNotFoundException` extends `IOException`.

In your code, all exceptions (except `OutOfMemoryError`) are subtypes of `java.lang.Exception`, hence the error. `OutOfMemoryError` is a subtype of `java.lang.Error`, which is a `Throwable`, but not an `Error`.

Here is a [more fine-grained diagram representing the hierarchy of all `java.lang.Exception`s within `Throwable`](http://beecrypt.sourceforge.net/doxygen/c++/classbeecrypt_1_1lang_1_1Exception__inherit__graph.png).

Hope this helped.

Finally, if you ***really*** want to catch all exceptions and errors in one catch block (a terrible idea, as others have pointed out), you could do one of the following:

```
catch (Exception | Error e)
```

or

```
catch (Throwable t)
```

Comment: I just read your comment on @Dima's answer. It now makes sense to me why you are catching all errors and exceptions.

Answer (score 3):

The code `catch (Exception  | OutOfMemoryError  e){ }` compiles because `OutOfMemoryError` is not an `Exception`, so `Exception` doesn't cover `OutOfMemoryError`.  [`OutOfMemoryError` is an `Error`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) and it is not an `Exception`.

It's usually not a good idea to catch `Error`s, because they are usually unrecoverable anyway.

Comment: Ok, but i don't have something general that Called "Error" like i have Exception so what should i do in order to catch all Errors?

Comment: If you insist on catching all `Error`s, then catch `Error`: `catch (Exception | Error e)`.

Comment: Ok i just now saw that Error is exist.
thank you, i will use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can catch `Throwable`, which is a superclass of everything, that can be thrown, errors or exceptions.

As pointed out previously though, this is not a good idea, and not something you should do. You should only be catching those exceptions from which you can meaningfully recover.

Comment: The purpose of my program is different than regular program. it should just run and when error appears start again(making a lot of network connection, so there are so many optional errors) so catch all the errors and exceptions is great solution for me.

Comment: If you are out of memory, or, perhaps, getting killed by OS because of some kind of resource restriction, or have a bug in the code, that just makes it die every time, catching and ignoring those errors isn't going to do you much good whether your program is "regular" or not.

Comment: I get this OutofMemoryException each 1-2 hours that my prog runs.
If I run the program again immediately after i got this error it works again great for 1-2 hours. so why should i run the program by myself each 1-2 hours if i can write on the catch to start again?

Comment: Note that i can't create less objects in my code and i did my code considering hardly  this error but its the best solution i got.

Comment: You don't need to catch the exception to start it again. Just let it exist and restart

Comment: what do you mean?
which functions should i use? can you give me code example?
i want it to restart automatically

Comment: no, I mean, outside of java. Just write a script, that keeps restarting your program ... For the record, I still think it is wrong (you are being lazy, and hacking a work around rather than debug your program and find a real solution)

Answer (score 1):

It is not allowed to specify two or more exceptions of a same hierarchy in the multi-catch statement.

Comment: Yes i understood that but still i can't understand how to create catch block that will catch all error or exception my program will get

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch 'everything'  you can catch (Throwable t) which which catch errors, exceptions, runtimeexceptions, etc... though I would recommend catching individual exceptions as you would likely want your app to handle different types of Exceptions/Errors/ differently.

Comment: Ok, and what the difference between doing this (Throwable t) to catch(Exception | Error e) or it's actually the same?

Comment: @user3100708 In theory, someone could create a class that directly extended `Throwable` and *not* `Exception` or `Error` but that would be an (ahem) *exceptionally* bad idea.