# Is there an equivalent of Python exceptions in Java?

Tags: java, python, exception

I'm new on Java, and I would like to know if Java has something like Python exception handling, where you **don't** have to specify the exception type. Something like:

```
try:
    f = open('text.tx', 'r')
except:
    #Note you don't have to specify the exception
    print "There's an error here"
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of Java exceptions: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: May be you should have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1075895/how-can-i-catch-all-the-exceptions-that-will-be-thrown-through-reading-and-writi)

Comment: This is bad practice in Python. You definitely shouldn't do it there. I guess the equivalent in Java is `catch (Exception e)`, although, probably that is equivalent to python `except Exception as e:`

Answer (score 2):

Every exception in Java is some sort of extension of `java.lang.Exception`. So you can always do:

```
try {
   // something that maybe fails
} catch (Exception e) { 
   // do something with the exception
}
```

It will catch any other type of exception, you just won't know what the *actual* exception is, without debugging.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is something called the try and catch block it looks something like this:

```
try
{
   //Code that may throw an exception
}catch(Exception e)
{
   //Code to be executed if the above exception is thrown
}
```

For your code above it could possibly be checked like this:

```
try
{
    File f = new File("New.txt");
} catch(FileNotFoundException ex)
{
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Hope this helps look at this for more information: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Answer (score 2):

You can't leave out the exception type, but the widest try-catch block would be:

```
try {
    // Some code
} catch(Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

which catches `Exceptions`, `Errors` and any other classes implementing `Throwable` that you might want to throw.

It would also be incredibly foolish to use that anywhere, especially in something as simple as file access. `IOException` is a checked exception, so whenever you're doing file operations you'll be reminded by the compiler to handle that exception. There's no need to do a catch-all, it only makes your code more brittle.